# I would like my card list to collapse into 2 columns, with header repeating

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive, bootstrap-cards

I am generating a `"table"` using bootstrap cards, fetching data via `$smarty`.
I would like to collapse the the table into 2 columns when the `viewport` gets small.

So that the header will be on the left, with attributes like: name, date, age. And the corresponding column on the right has the data in line, like: Fred, 12.12.2012, 41.

Tried using the built in responsive feature in bootstrap cards, however when the `viewport` gets small, everything collapses into 1 column. With the header on top.
I have tried `jquery.basictable.min.js` but it would not work.

Simple graphic of desired result:

```
name | stewie
date | 124214
age  | 9000

name | bob
date | 45845
age  | 65

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">name</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">date</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">age</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">stewie</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">124214</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">9000</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">bob</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">45845</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="font-medium-3">65</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'll provide a link here to show what I would like to achieve:
http://www.jerrylow.com/basictable/demo/

I assume that CSS could do a lot of what I need, but I am unable to find relevant information.

Comment: use `@media max-width` to trigger 2 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS IS OLD ANSWER:**

> Not best solution but you can try this
>
> **Main factor is**
>
> - `@media screen and (max-width:768px)` will detect mobile for responsive
> - `flex-direction: [column/row] !important` will change orientation of table
>
> ```css
> @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
>   body {
>     /* Yellow mean mobile */
>     background-color: #ff0 !important;
>   }
>   .card {
>     flex-direction: row !important;
>   }
>   .card .row {
>     flex-direction: column !important;
>     white-space: nowrap;
>     margin-right: 0;
>     margin-left: 0;
>   }
>   .card .card-body {
>     display: flex;
>     flex-direction: row !important;
>     white-space: nowrap;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>
> <div class="container-fluid">
>   <div class="card">
>     <div class="card-header">
>       <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">name</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">date</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">age</span>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="card-body">
>       <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">stewie</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">124214</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">9000</span>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">bob</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">45845</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="col-4">
>           <span class="font-medium-3">65</span>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> *This is not solved*

**UPDATE:** I have spend much time to find your solution with jQuery

So you need to use jQuery

so one way is **make new element** to toggle mobile and desktop view

Like this

If it help please submit this as answer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resposiveTable();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resposiveTable(this);
  });
});

function resposiveTable(ele) {
  var win = $(window); //this = window
  if (win.width() < 768) {
    $(document.body).css("background-color", "lightyellow");
    $('.responsive-CardTB .card').hide();
    //GENERATE responsive
    if ($(".responsive-CardTB .mobile-content").length < 1) {
      var mobileview = document.createElement("div");
      $(mobileview).append('xxx');
      $(mobileview).addClass('mobile-content container');
      $('.responsive-CardTB')
        .append(mobileview);
    }
    $('.responsive-CardTB .mobile-content').show();
    updateContent();
  } else {
    $(document.body).css("background-color", "");
    $('.responsive-CardTB .card').show();
    $('.responsive-CardTB .mobile-content').hide();
  }
}

function updateContent() {
  var mbcontent = $(".responsive-CardTB .mobile-content")
  mbcontent.empty();
  $('.responsive-CardTB .card .card-body .row')
    .each(function(i, ele) {
      var row = $(document.createElement("div"));
      row.addClass('card container');

      $(ele).find('.col-4').each(function(index, element) {
        var rowdata = $(document.createElement("div"));
        rowdata.addClass('row');

        var header =
          $('.responsive-CardTB .card .card-header .row .col-4')
          .eq(index).html();
        var colhead = $(document.createElement("div"));
        colhead.addClass('card-header col-4').html(header);
        rowdata.append(colhead);

        var colbody = $(document.createElement("div"));
        colbody.addClass('card-body col-8').html($(element).html());
        rowdata.append(colbody);

        row.append(rowdata);
      });

      mbcontent.append(row);
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid responsive-CardTB">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">date</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">age</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">stewie</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">124214</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">9000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">bob</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">45845</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="font-medium-3">65</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One issue with this is that everything goes into 1 row. So we get something like:
attributes | data | data
Instead of:
attributes | data
attributes | data

I would really like for the header to repeat for each row.

Comment: may be need to use `javascript` I didn't use use because you didn't tag it

Comment: you need jQuery or Pure javascript?

Comment: I'm honestly fine with both js and jquery

Comment: I have update my new code already. I have spend so much time with. sorry for late

Comment: @user2008560 here for you